# How can I subscribe to an Event Emitter from a Component through a Service?

Tags: angular, socket.io, observable, angular-services, eventemitter

In my `Angular 5` websocket(`socket.io`) based `Component`, I do the following:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  socket: any;
  latestData: any[];
  constructor() {
    this.latestData = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
    this.socket.on('connect', function() {
      console.log('connected');
    });

    this.socket.on('broadcast', this.handleData);
  }

  handleData(data) {
    this.latestData = data;
  }
}
```

So, whenever a `broadcast` event in emitted over the docket, I call the `this.handleData` function with that data emitted.

However, I would now like to deletegate the event handling to the service, and subscribe to a method in my service.

However, the `handleData` should still be triggered whenever a `broadcast` is done. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What `EventEmitter`? Don't use `EventEmitter` for anything but `@Output()`s in components and directives.

Comment: The library(`socket.io-client`) emits events, see the `ngOnInit`

Comment: That doesn't make it an [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter). It's an "event emitter" at best

Comment: Ah I see, I'm more of a node.js guy, and anything like that is `EventEmitter` in Node.JS

Comment: I see. Please try to disambiguate if you use it again in an Angular context ;-)
I don't know node.js and wasn't aware of that.

Comment: What about just moving all the code to a service? I don't understand yet what the problem is.

Comment: I can move the code to a service yes, but how do I return an observable from the service when the `broadcast` event is triggered? And how do I make sure `handleData` is called every time `broadcast` happens

Comment: Why do you want to move the code to a service if you only need it in the component?

Comment: I will need to subscribe to the event from other components too

Comment: What part exactly is the problem? If you add an observable to a service that emits an event when `socket.on` emits an event and then inject the service to every component where you want to subscribe and subscribe, it should do what you want. You need to decide if what you want components to receive when they are subscribe after some events were already received.

Comment: First time working with angular is the issue, tbh.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction should be a good start. Search for `observable`